# generate random characters in my case

Tags: java, base64

I need to generated **random** 32 characters string with the use of `SecureRandom` class. I tried with generating 32 byte array then use Base64 encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bytes);

new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
```

But this code generate a string with more than 32 characters. How can I get random 32 characters while still using `SecureRandom` class ?

Comment: You needed 32 and your code generates more than 32, why can't you pick up the first 32? It would still be random...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode 22 to 24 bytes instead.

When encoding this amount, the resulting Base64 encoded string should contain exactly 32 characters although some of them might be `=` marks based on whether its 22 or 23 bytes due to padding.

If you don't want the `=` marks, just encode 24 bytes and no padding will be added.

If you are more interested on how the padding or Base64 encoding works, the current [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is quite detailed.

e.g. change your code accordingly:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[24];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bytes);

new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes)); // Should be 32 characters in length.
```

Comment: What is the rule of Base64  appending N characters? How do you know 24 byte encoding results 32 characters?

Comment: Base64 uses 64 = 2^6 "digits" - hence has 6 bits payload per byte/char. 4 chars suffice for 3 bytes exactly. So 32 chars Base64 will have a payload of exactly 24 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using single line of code. Use `org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils`from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library.

**Code :**

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(32);
```